# nodejs server script unknown result

Tags: node.js

I am unable to understand when ever I send request from a browser my variable 'i' increments twice. below is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

var add = (function(){
    var i = 0;
    return function() { i+=1;return i;};
})();

var handleRequest = function (req, res){

    res.writeHead(200 , {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    res.end('Welcome to node Training\n' + add());
};

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

I am novice, I tried searching but not able to find something relevant,
please provide relevant sources for learning, so I may better understand the flow of programs.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When checking in my browser in the dev tools, you see that every request is giving i++, that includes the request for favicon.ico.. so each time you enter your site in your browser, 2 requests are being made.